# CSS: Two divs side by side, in autosizing table cell

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 2 divs in a table cell. I want the left hand div to size according to it's content, and I want the right hand div to float right. Both should be vertically centered.

The table cell autosizes like this:

```
<td style="width: 1px;">
   ...
</td>
```

**[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Homeliss/K8y9M/)**

Answer (score 6):

Add `display:table-cell` and remove float from both the divs and remove width from the td

```
.left{
    font-size: 2em; 
    line-height: 1.4;
    background: #FFCC66; 
    display:table-cell
}
.right{
    background: #CCFF66;
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K8y9M/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the snippet below, % will make the size start at a that number and auto resize

```
#div1
{ float: left; height:60%; width: 40%; }

#div2
{ float: right; height:60%; width: 60%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase td width

```
<td style="width:56px;">
 <div style="float: left; font-size: 2em; line-height: 1.4; background: #FFCC66">$50</div>
 <div style="float: right; background: #CCFF66; margin-top:10px;"></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below e.g. Both Div is vertically align according each other

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
      <td>
          <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">tetstingdfsdfds <br>test </div>

          <div style="text-align:right; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">right side ...</div>
      </td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you add another cell, so you have one for the price, and the other for the arrow, like this:

```
<td style="background: #66FFCC; vertical-align: middle; width: 1px;">
    <div style="font-size: 2em; line-height: 1.4;background: #FFCC66;">$50</div>
</td>
<td style="background: #66FFCC; vertical-align: middle; width: 1px;">
    <div style="background: #CCFF66;">&gt;</div>
</td>
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6k4T5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 1px;` from the `td` and add `display: inline-block` to the both `div`'s:

```
.left{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background: #FA0;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
.right{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    background: #AF0;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 2.8em;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1ttLy12/).